# How to get the message from the signature as a receiver

Tags: java, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, private-key, java-security

If I use server-client method, the client update signature using data(message).
And send to server. How does the server get the message from this signature?

```
final String message = "Hello world is a stupid message to be signed";

final KeyPair keyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA").generateKeyPair();

final Signature privSig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");

privSig.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());

privSig.update(message.getBytes());

byte[] signature = privSig.sign();

final Signature pubSig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");

pubSig.initVerify(keyPair.getPublic());
pubSig.update(message.getBytes());

System.out.println(pubSig.verify(signature));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature contains the message in a mangled or digested form. You cannot extract the message from it. You need to send the plain message along with the signature to the receiver. Otherwise, they cannot verify the validity.